# MATLAB and ATi GPU

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

How do I use my ATi 5470M for computation on MATLAB 2010a

Also, Can I enable my CPU and GPU to do the thing in parallel, together?

I'm new to GPU computing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start by looking at the [OpenCL Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30109-opencl-toolbox-v0-11). You can also try out [Jacket](http://www.accelereyes.com/).

Comment: Jacket works with CUDA supported cards, meaning, only nVidia based cards are supported.